# Can some one help me on django with this ImportError: cannot import name 'product_detial_view' from 'products.views'

Tags: python, django, django-urls, importerror

I'm a noob in django and i watched some tutorial but I ran into an error that I can't really fix, and just here to ask if anyone can help me out. I'm using mac with bash, python 3.7.0, sublime text, and the tutorial is in youtube, I really need someone who could solve this problem for me thanks

```css
Performing system checks... Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10ed24378>Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
line 225,
in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
line 120,
in inner_run self.check(display_num_errors=True) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
line 364,
in check include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
line 351,
in _run_checks return checks.run_checks(**kwargs) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
line 73,
in run_checks new_errors=check(app_configs=app_configs) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
line 13,
in check_url_config return check_resolver(resolver) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
line 23,
in check_resolver return check_method() File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
line 399,
in check for pattern in self.url_patterns: File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
line 36,
in __get__ res=instance.__dict__[self.name]=self.func(instance) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
line 540,
in url_patterns patterns=getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
line 36,
in __get__ res=instance.__dict__[self.name]=self.func(instance) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
line 533,
in urlconf_module return import_module(self.urlconf_name) File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py",
line 127,
in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import 
File " <frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load 
File " <frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File " <frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked 
File " <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module 
File " <frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed 
File "/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/src/trydjango/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
from products.views import product_detial_view,
product_create_view ImportError: cannot import name 'product_detial_view' from 'products.views' (/Users/evangui88/Dev/trydjango/src/products/views.py)
```

Comment: What's the content of `products/views.py`? Specifically, is there some entity named `product_detial_view` in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you spelt detail wrong in the urls.py?

```
'product_detial_view'

*'product_detail_view'*
```

Comment: oops i miss that and i used almost half an hour studying that thanks a lot

Comment: @evangui You can click the check box next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from your products app in your views.py file. Check to see if you have any view function called "product_detail_view" or if there's a misspelling in there.

Also, it could be that you have no view function of that name. Check properly.

See if you can share your views.py app from your "products app", to get a more detailed response.

Comment: oh yeah i saw the misspell and now it working all fine